# SQL query to select all rows where values of field occured N or more times?

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose we have table:

```
create table EVENT("id" number, "date" DATE, "value" number);
```

I want to get all rows where each selected *id* occured **N** or more times. So for:

```
    id  |    date    | value
   --------------------------
    1   | 2011-01-01 |  100
    1   | 2011-01-02 |  200
    2   | 2011-01-05 |  300
    2   | 2011-03-15 |  800
    3   | 2011-02-01 |  400
    4   | 2011-01-01 |  500
    4   | 2011-04-21 |  600
    4   | 2011-01-01 |  700
```

and **N** == 2 I get all rows except *id=3*, and for **N** == 3 I get only rows with *id=4*...

I work with Oracle but seems this type of query require some new knowledge of SQL for me...

Comment: You need the whole rows or just the ids?

Comment: Whole rows... Thanks for question.

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT "id",
       "date",
       "value"
FROM   (SELECT EVENT.*,
               COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY "id") AS CNT
        FROM   EVENT)
WHERE  CNT >= 3
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/97a57/2)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM Event
WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id 
             FROM Event
             GROUP BY Id 
             HAVING COUNT(*) > N)
```

Edit: Martin Smith's answer should have the best performance, the only downside being that you have to list out fields to avoid including the COUNT() in the results.

Answer (score 1):

```
select  *
from    Event
where   id in
        (
        select  id
        from    Event
        group by
                id
        having  count(*) > 3 -- For N = 3
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
SELECT *
FROM tmp
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM tmp GROUP BY id 
             HAVING COUNT(*) > N)
```

Update value of `N` as your condition says.

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f1987/5)

Comment: On SO it is unreal to hear why ((. Thanks for your answer! +1

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM Event
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS Cnt FROM Event GROUP BY id
) AS C ON Event.id = C.id
WHERE C.Cnt >= 3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
  e.* 
from 
  event e, 
  (select e1.id, count(*) as id_num from event e1 group by e1.id) as e2
where
  e.id = e2.id
  and e2.id_num >= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM   EVENT
GROUP  BY "id"
HAVING ( COUNT("id") > N - 1
         AND COUNT("id") < N + 1 );
```

Comment: `SELECT * ... GROUP  BY "id"` won't work. The only valid column references in the `SELECT` list would be `id` or aggregated columns.

Comment: @MartinSmith yes, that why I ask question. I never perform such type of queries so ask...